# Hibernate Remote MySQL Database through SSH

Tags: java, hibernate, ssh

I will be deploying a Web Application on a JBoss server and will using JPA/Hibernate for the persistence layer. I want to connect to a Remote MySQL database which I access through SSH with a certificate.

How can I do this programatically in combination with persistence.xml

Answer (score 2):

If you want connect to database via SSH tunnel I can recommend you Java implementation of SSH.
Supports authorization with certificates, port-forwarding, the connection through a proxy, etc.

See

- [**JSch**](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)
- [**JSch examples**](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/)